# react-rte giving TypeError: r.getEditorState is not a function in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs project and it has a react-rte component
the react-rte component is displayed correctly but when I go to some other component and click back in the browsers back button I get the following error:

`Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: r.getEditorState is not a function`

When I comment out the  react-rte  componnet the error no longer occurs

**react-rte component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//import the component
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });

const MyStatefulEditor = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  console.log(value.toString("html"));

  useEffect(() => {
    const importModule = async () => {
      //import module on the client-side to get `createEmptyValue` instead of a component
      const module = await import("react-rte");
      console.log(module);
      setValue(module.createEmptyValue());
    };
    importModule();
  }, []);

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  return <RichTextEditor value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />;
};

MyStatefulEditor.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
};

export default MyStatefulEditor;
```

Comment: Rather than dynamically importing `react-rte` in this component, you should just use regular imports for `react-rte`, and dynamically import this custom component (`MyStatefulEditor`) wherever it's used with `next/dynamic` and `{ ssr: false }`.

Comment: @juliomalves can pls help me with this ! can u pls tell me what i must be changing through an answer. ur comment is not clear to me

Comment: As suggested try `import RichTextEditor from 'react-rte';` instead of `const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });`

Comment: I can see you are importing `react-rte` twice, why are you doing another import in the useEffect call?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez i tryed ur answer now i am getting this error  Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition to check `value` before rendering `RichTextEditor`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
//import the component
const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });

const MyStatefulEditor = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const importModule = async () => {
      //import module on the client-side to get `createEmptyValue` instead of a component
      const module = await import("react-rte");
      setValue(module.createEmptyValue());
    };
    importModule();
  }, [router.pathname]);

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  //if `value` from react-rte is not generated yet, you should not render `RichTextEditor`
  if (!value) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RichTextEditor value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />;
};

MyStatefulEditor.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func
};

export default MyStatefulEditor;
```

You can verify the implementation with [the live example](https://oe5f53.sse.codesandbox.io/) and [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2-route-inspection-in-custom-app-forked-oe5f53?file=/components/MyStatefulEditor.js)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const RichTextEditor = dynamic(() => import("react-rte"), { ssr: false });


const MyStatefulEditor = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // set the state value using the package available method
    setValue(RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue())
  }, []);

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value.toString("html"));
    }
  };

  return <RichTextEditor value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />;
};

MyStatefulEditor.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
};

export default MyStatefulEditor;
```

Like I mention in my previous comment, I notice you are importing the `react-rte` package twice.

In the `useEffect` hook you do an import to initialise the `value` state, by looking at the example code found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rte)

You can achieve that using `RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue()` which comes from the already imported package.

You will noticed that I change the import, is not dynamic, try that and if is it works if so then try doing the dynamic import if that is what you need.

Comment: i tryed ur answer now i am getting this error Server Error ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Try now with the dynamic import as you previously had

Comment: I have changed the answer, apparently using nextjs, you will need to use dynamic import as some packages are bound to the window object which is not present in the nodejs server object [source](https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97)

Comment: there is no error but  react-rte compoent is not getting dispayed now

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but did you check that the `MyStatefulEditor` component is rendered from its parent properly? simply try `<div>MyStatefulEditor</div>` in the return to check, without looking at how the component is used from its parent is hard to tell why is not rendering